# $N_{L/K}$ is an open map

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of $p$-adic fields.  Is the norm map $N_{L/K}: L \rightarrow K$ an open map?

At the very least, what is the easiest way (say, without using local class field theory) to see that the images of $L^{\ast}$ and $\mathcal O_L^{\ast}$ under the norm $N_{L/K}$ are open subgroups of $K^{\ast}$?

Comment: I just realized that you can use Hensel's lemma to show that $N_{L/K}(\mathcal O_L^{\ast})$ is open in $\mathcal O_K$.  If $n = [L : K]$, then every $x \in \mathcal O_K$ for which $|1-x|$ is sufficient small is an $n$th power from $K$.  But $\mathcal O_K^{\ast n} \subseteq N_{L/K}(\mathcal O_L^{\ast})$.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s see whether I can give a sketch of an argument that will hold up.

To answer both of your questions, it should be enough to show that for $n$ big enough, $N^L_K(1+p^n\mathscr O_L)$ is open in $K^*$. Now for $n$ big enough, the $p$-adic logarithm maps $1+p^n\mathscr O_L$ onto $p^n\mathscr O_L$, isomorphically as Galois modules. The “big enough” should be $n\ge1$ for $p\ne2$, and $n\ge2$ for $p=2$. The map is one-to-one and onto, homomorphism, and respects Galois because its coefficients are in $\Bbb Q_p$.

In view of the above, the Norm on $1+p^n\mathscr O_L$ is isomorphic to the Trace on $p^n\mathscr O_L$, which I’m sure you can see is an open map.